# IP instead of hostname

Tags: syslog-ng

In logs from syslog clients I got hostname field. How can I force syslog-ng to put there IP addres instead hostname? It's only thing I want to change, don't want to be forced to make full message template if possible.

I need to do this on Linux clients, Windows clients, and on Balabit Store Box, I guess for each of these solution can be different.

Answer (score 0):

For linux, Use $SOURCEIP macro for IP.